# laravel valet: "unsecure" continues to redirect to https

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I tried out valet's "secure" functionality. It worked well, but ultimately, it wasn't working well with the rest of my stack so I tried running "valet unsecure sitename" per the documentation. It nonetheless seems to still be in some way linked: if I attempted to navigate to the site now, it runs into a redirect loop. I have tried re-starting the server, etc. Nothing seems to work. If I re-run the "valet secure sitename" and navigate to https://sitename.dev, it will begin working once again. It seems to be stuck on "secure" mode no matter what once you run the command once.

Has anyone else run into this and is there a fix for it? I could not find anything in reference except a few people with the same unanswered question on some random sites.

Comment: Did you try restarting laravel and or restarting your computer and then try again?

Comment: @rhand yes. i never figured this one out.

Comment: And do you have the latest Laravel version running too? There were issues with OSX Sierra. See https://laravel-news.com/2016/09/troubleshooting-laravel-valet-on-macos-sierra/

Comment: well, honestly when i asked this question a few months ago sierra wasn't even out. i went through several processes of starting and re-starting valet and my computer, deleting the dir, deleting certs saved in my keychain, generating new certs and dirs. i never figured out how to fix it.

Comment: Well, perhaps the new version will help. Funnily enough I cannot get valet share working atm. Opened a thread for it at SO. However, local server runs just fine using the latest version . If I cannot get sharing to work I will move back to Vagrant or search for alternatives.

Comment: cool i''ll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is wrong but it may be related to your browser, your browser may be trying to redirect you to a "more secure" "version" of the site, that is to use the HTTPS protocol.

I've had had this problem, before and the solution depends on the browser you're using.

The easiest way to tell if this a Valet issue vs a browser issue is to try to access the non-https version of your domain with a fresh browser, try other browser or download another one.

If is a browser isse google something like "clear HSTS on "

(I know the question is 1 year old but  some people may come from google having this problem due to their browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I think is chrome setting problem.
I change to use Safari and Postman that can connect http. Not return to https.
But return 404 not found.

Afetr I uninstall valet, and install repeat again. It works http in Safari.

reference
[Uninstall Laravel Valet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276967/uninstall-laravel-valet)

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

As of [Chrome 63](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) because .dev is a valid gTLD that can be used by the public and Chrome has been growing the preload list .

The options are as follows:

- do not use Chrome 63 or later
- You can use the gTLD .test which could eventually have the issue but is presently held by the IETF for internal purposes
- IETF also has a [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-let-localhost-be-localhost-06) for the .localhost name to be mapped to the local loopback address.

Comment: This question is more than a year old, and as such, *today's* change to Chrome is unlikely to have been OP's issue.