# Uninstall Laravel Valet

Tags: php, uninstallation, laravel-5.3, laravel-valet

I installed Valet for the first time and I had some problems listed below:

1. It throws an error saying:

> Unable to determine linked PHP.

Even though I have PHP 7.1 installed by [php-osx.liip.ch](http://php-osx.liip.ch) so it just goes ahead and installs PHP 7.0 with homebrew anyway!

2. In the non-laravel projects my localhost does not work and it responds:

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

and then Valet itself does not work either!

3. I'm getting an error on Valet domains with message:

> This site can’t be reached laravel_from_scratch.dev’s server DNS
>   address could not be found.

So I decided to uninstall it by running `$ valet uninstall`, it returns the corresponding response but then when I'm running `$ valet` it is all there! How to uninstall it correctly?

**BTW**, I posted this issue also on the [Valet GitHub page](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/200).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I guess I find the solution after a little bit playing around.

It seems Valet `uninstall` command does not work as expected. To uninstall it first run the composer command to uninstall the php dependencies:

`$ composer global remove laravel/valet`

then to uninstall the dependencies installed with the Homebrew, first run;

```
$ brew list
```

just so you know we are in the same page then if you see `dnsmasq` and `php70` in case you do not want them or you have php7 installed in another approach (like me) run:

```
$ brew uninstall dnsmasq
```

and

```
$ brew uninstall php70
```

Then go to your user directory and delete the `.valet` hidden directory or run the terminal command like so:

```
$ sudo rm -r ~/.valet
```

Comment: Thank you! Your instructions were exactly what I needed.

Comment: If you get a "directory is not empty error", try: `sudo rm -r  ~/.valet` instead to recursively empty and delete the directory.

Comment: In case anyone runs into this, when I uninstalled valet like this, I found the xcode-select, namely the xcode command line tool got uninstalled too, need to re-install it after reboot your mac.

Comment: To use Laravel Valet again, remember to reinstall `dnsmasq` and also reinstall or update `xcode-select`. You should update xcode-select via command line using `softwareupdate --install <software>` replacing `software` with the xcode-select version found after the asterisk using `softwareupdate --list`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the directory changed from `~/.valet` to `~/.config/valet`

Answer (score 33):

An official response here:
https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/341#issuecomment-287048987

```
valet uninstall --force
sudo brew services stop nginx
sudo brew services stop php70
sudo brew services stop dnsmasq
brew uninstall nginx
brew uninstall php70
brew uninstall dnsmasq
rm -rf ~/.valet
rm /usr/local/bin/valet
```

Comment: One-liner: `valet uninstall && composer global remove laravel/valet && sudo brew services stop nginx php70 dnsmasq && brew uninstall nginx php70 dnsmasq && rm -rf ~/.valet`

Comment: In my case, I wanted to keep PHP: `valet uninstall && composer global remove laravel/valet && sudo brew services stop nginx dnsmasq && brew uninstall nginx dnsmasq && rm -rf ~/.valet`