# Question: How to solve laravel valet No such file or directory?

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-valet

when I was installing laravel valet I got an error saying:

```
/bin/bash: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\/../laravel/valet/valet: No such file or directory
```

I already required it with composer by this command:

```
composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows
```

and then using this command to install it:

```
valet install
```

and I get the error as shown at the beginning,

and last but not least thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it using composer as below:
`composer global require laravel/valet`

Reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet)

To uninstall the previous version please use below commands:
`$ composer global remove laravel/valet`

If there is any dependencies or any .valet hidden files, you can remove those as well.

Comment: but how can I uninstall the previous one?

Comment: @svqo to remove previous installation you can follow steps here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276967/uninstall-laravel-valet

Comment: thanks, but can you edit your answer to accept it?

Comment: @svqo good point, just updated resonse :) Thanks